# ¿Como hacer un plot de una regresión con dos variables predictoras? Python

Tags: python, machine-learning

Un saludo, realice una **regresión lineal** bastante basica con

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
```

el modelo se define así:

```
X_pred = X[['TV', 'Radio']]
lm = LinearRegression()
lm.fit(X_pred, Y)
```

¿Como puedo hacer el plot de la regresión con dos variables predictoras?

Answer (score 2):

No estoy realmente seguro si esto es lo que necesitas, pero se me ocurre hacer un gráfico 3D, dado que la variable `Y` depende tanto de `X.TV` como de `X.Radio` ya que estás haciendo una Regresión Lineal Múltiple de este tipo:

[image]

que para este caso en particular es:

[image]

el `intercepto` lo obtienes con `lm.intercept_` y los `coeficiente1` y `coeficiente2` los obtienes con `lm.coef_[0]` y `lm.coef_[1]` respectivamente, y `TV` y `Radio` son `df['TV']` y `df['Radio']` respectivamente, con esto ya podemos hacer nuestro gráfico en 3D.

Usaremos `Axes3D` de matplotlib, [aquí](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html) puedes encontrar la documentación.

Importamos los módulos:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
```

Definimos las variables que vamos a usar:

```
X = df['TV']
Y = df['Radio']
Z = lm.intercept_+lm.coef_[0]*df['TV']+lm.coef_[1]*df['Radio']
```

donde `Z` es la Regresión Lineal Múltiple, luego procedemos a hacer el gráfico:

```
fig = plt.figure().gca(projection='3d')
fig.plot(X, Y, Z)
fig.set_xlabel('TV')
fig.set_ylabel('Radio')
fig.set_zlabel('Y')
plt.show()
```

donde obtendrías un gráfico similar a esto:

[image]

Otra opción es hacer algo como esto:

[image]

que es lo más recomendado, hacer las dos regresiones en el mismo gráfico, ya que esto hace que el gráfico sea más fácil de interpretar que un gráfico 3D, sí estás interesado en esto último, te invito a darle un vistazo a esta [publicación](https://towardsdatascience.com/simple-and-multiple-linear-regression-with-python-c9ab422ec29c).

Comment: Que buena respuesta, te agradezco mucho crack.